# Why do Android activities have to pass data in intent extras?

Tags: android, memory, process

Specifically, my question is: what is the memory model for Android applications? Why is it that I have to pass data from activity to another activity via intents? Doesn't the entire application process have shared memory? I'd be grateful for any good resources about this on the web!

Answer (score 0):

The typical application is in one process but like any java application, the various objects/classes in the application have their own access restrictions.  Each Activity is a separate class and it's not a good idea to have everything public, thus you pass around what you need to.

Another reason is that sometimes you want to launch another Activity and don't want the first Activity to remain in memory any longer.  Thus, the first can pass on what it needs to and then be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for starting an Activity you need to use an Intent, so why not taking advantage of that and pass the data by the Intent.

About the shared memory, actually there is an interface in Android called SharedPreferences which lets you save some important data and access to it as if it were a HashMap. You can save data like this:

`Editor tEditor = SharedPreferences.edit();
 tEditor.putString("key", "value");
 tEditor.apply();`

And then you can retrieve the saved data like this:

```
SharedPreferences.getString("key", "");
```

You can study some more about the SharedPreferences [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)